# Misaligned Segmented Control for Nav Bar (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

Want to try to add a segmented control (centered) via the story board. Here's what I want it to look like and it works via the storyboard.

[image]

Here's what it turns out like on the emulator/phone.

[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The plus sign has some insets (4 on each side, but I don't think thats the main reason for alignment)

Here is the heiarchy?

[image]

Comment: Would you please share your view hierarchy ..?? Are you using segmented control as `titleVIew`..??

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `titleView` for `navigationItem`. Currently you are dealing it as a `barButtonItem` see how to set `titleView`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Darn, this was a VERY good guess. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem as I just tried it. Perhaps its more the misalignment of the segment controller? Not really sure.

Comment: I've done it many times. I did it now, check updated answer. There might be something which disturb your `navigationBar`. Or if you can share your project link i can send you fixed. :) New screenshot is taken from simulator

Comment: Man its whole project. Can you subset it for me I'm not able to build dont have libraries on my office mac.